# Creating a new object with different variables from the text

Tags: java, arraylist

I am working on a homework assignment and stuck.

The list runner should show at the end, the name of the runners and which ageGroup they are in, like junior, senior, etc..

I am just stumped on how to get the values after the ageGroup is sorted into the ranks, any small pointers would be appreciated. Using `BlueJ` if that helps.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import ou.*;

/**
 * Write a description of class MarathonAdmin here.
 *
 * @author (your name)
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class MarathonAdmin
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own

    private Runner runners;
    List<String> runner = new ArrayList<String>();

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class MarathonAdmin
     */
    public MarathonAdmin()
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        List<String> runner = new ArrayList<String>();

    }

    /**
     * An example of a method - replace this comment with your own
     *
     * @param  y   a sample parameter for a method
     * @return     the sum of x and y 
     */
    public void readInRunners()
    {
        // put your code here
        String pathName = OUFileChooser.getFilename();
        File aFile = new File(pathName);
        BufferedReader bufferedFileReader = null;

        try
        {
            String runnerLine;
            String ageGroup;
            Scanner runScanner;
            bufferedFileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(aFile));
            runnerLine = bufferedFileReader.readLine();

            while(runnerLine != null)
            {
                runScanner = new Scanner(runnerLine);
                runScanner.useDelimiter(",");

                runnerLine = runScanner.next();
                ageGroup = runScanner.next();

                for (String run : runner)

                    if (Integer.parseInt(ageGroup) < 18)
                    {
                        System.out.println(runnerLine + " : Junior");
                    }
                if (Integer.parseInt(ageGroup) > 55)
                {
                    System.out.println(runnerLine + " : Senior");
                }
                if (Integer.parseInt(ageGroup) > 18 && Integer.parseInt(ageGroup) < 55)
                {
                    System.out.println(runnerLine + " : Standard");
                }

                this.runners = new Runner();
                runner.add(runnerLine);
                runner.add(ageGroup);

                runnerLine = bufferedFileReader.readLine();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception anExpection)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: " + anExpection);
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                bufferedFileReader.close();
            }
            catch(Exception anException)
            {
                System.out.println("Error: " + anException);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Always tag your questions with the language you're using, please.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question the right way, this is one way to solve it:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> ageGroups = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
        ageGroups.put("Junior", new ArrayList<String>());
        ageGroups.put("Senior", new ArrayList<String>());
        ageGroups.put("Standard", new ArrayList<String>());

        for (String run : runner) {

            if (Integer.parseInt(ageGroup) < 18) {
                ageGroups.get("Junior").add(run);
                System.out.println(runnerLine + " : Junior");
            }
            if (Integer.parseInt(ageGroup) > 55) {
                System.out.println(runnerLine + " : Senior");
                ageGroups.get("Senior").add(run);

            }
            if (Integer.parseInt(ageGroup) > 18 && Integer.parseInt(ageGroup) < 55) {
                System.out.println(runnerLine + " : Standard");
                ageGroups.get("Standard").add(run);

            }

        }
```

Later on to get all runners of a certain group, you just call:

```
ArrayList<String> seniors = ageGroups.get("Senior")
```

The reason I use a HasMap is that you can now easily handle all classes of runners, especially if you add more groups/classes.

Edit: Afterwards I now can see that this many wasn't exactly what you where looking for, but I'll leave it since it could still be helpful.